# When can I use "the share of" to refer to the proportion of something?

Tags: phrase-usage

**Context:** It's an IELTS test where we have to make comparisons of the trends given in the chart. I attached one of the two pictures of the tests so you can have a better grasp of what the chart is like.

1. **The share of** the government’s budget on roads and transportation in Portugal started at about 27%, after which it saw a progressive decrease to 20% in 2005.
2. Similarly, **the share of** teenage boys who said they often went to the park was far higher than that of girls, with respective figures being 25% and 12%.

Is the phrase **the share of** used correctly in the above sentences? When can I use **the share of** to refer to the proportion of something?

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't use ***share*** for either context, because it implies someone ***deciding*** how to divide some finite resource (usually, *fairly* or *logically*) among those who need it. Which sorta works for example #1, but not #2. No such problems exist with, say, ***proportion***.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the expression is used correctly.  You can think of a phase like "the share of boys" as equivalent to "the fraction of boys".